# Trying to do a loop that will use certain columns from df, get error : KeyError: '[0 1 2 6 7] not in index'

Tags: python, pandas

```py
mor = pd.read_excel('/MorTables.xlsx',skiprows=3,usecols=[0,9,10,11,12,14,15,16])

mor.columns = mor.iloc[0]
mor_rev = {'test1':[0,1,2,6,7],'test2':[0,3,4,6,7]}
mor1 = pd.DataFrame (mor_rev)

for k,v in mor1.items():
    tab = mor[v][1:]                     
    MorTab = tab[[0,1,2]] 
    ImTab = tab[[0,3,4]]
```

Currently this bombs on the line tab = mor[v][1:] stating key error:[0,1,2,6,7] not in index

Comment: Maybe you should provide an example of what /MorTables.xlsx looks like (or equivalently the mor dataframe). Also, are you aware that in your example v is a Pandas Series as you can read in the official [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html)?

Comment: table1  table2  table3  table4 
t ind1 ind2 ind1 ind2 ind1 ind2 ind1 ind2
0 0.001783 0.001801 0.001730 0.001748 0.001730 0.001748 0.001730 0.001748
1 0.000446 0.000450 0.000433 0.000437 0.000433 0.000437 0.000433 0.000437